# Diagnosing persistent Flash streaming failure for DRM content

Tags: 12.04, firefox, flash, streaming

I'm trying to implement the fixes from Adobe (as mentioned in [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169318/how-can-i-watch-the-nbc-olympics-2012-usa)) but I'm having no success.

I'm running 64-bit 12.04. When I try the Flash test as described on [this Adobe guide](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/flash-player-11-problems-playing.html#id_16163):

> 1. First, launch the Adobe demo video player container: http://drmtest2.adobe.com:8080/SVP/SampleVideoPlayer_FP.html 
>     Note the Adobe Flash Player version in the lower left of the demo video shell. Make sure that indicate 11.2 or higher
> 2. Play sample protected content.
>      Enter the following URL in the field "Input the video URL: (case-sensitive)
>      http://drmtest2.adobe.com:8080/Content/anonymous.f4v
> 3. Press the [Play] button at the bottom of the video container.

Well that doesn't work. From that test page, when I select the "Show DRM Events" checkbox I get "Error #3344 [MissingAdobeCPModule]", and then it just sits there and nothing plays.

I've installed the HAL (several times) and cleared out the directories from my home `.adobe` directory as those instructions say, restarted Firefox, etc.

The Flash info page says "You have version 11,2,202,160 installed" and that 236 is the more up-to-date version, but I can't figure out how to install that. (I've tried, but to no avail; I just end up with 160).

So does anybody have ideas on what to do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK well that was dumb. I had been installing (and re-installing) `flashplugin-installer`.  When I instead switched to `adobe-flashplugin`, that brought my version up to 236 (that is, 11,2,202,236) and it also made the test page work.

Subsequently, a test at the NBC streaming site also worked.

Thus, it appears that in addition to doing the HAL stuff as described in [the other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169318/how-can-i-watch-the-nbc-olympics-2012-usa), it may also be necessary to be running the latest Flash version. For me, that required installing `adobe-flashplugin` instead of `flashplugin-installer`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd followed most of the advice I could find online, but ran across these extra steps to get the HAL working.  It comes from a post on Amazon's Prime Instant Video support thread:

Stephen Gutknecht says:

```
On a new (virgin) install of Ubuntu 13.04 x64/x32 - there are some steps that I don't see getting enough attention.

In addition to:

close your Chromium/Chrome and Firefox:
sudo apt-get install libhal1 hal

***also do***

sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi/preprobe
sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi/information
/usr/sbin/hald --daemon=yes --verbose=yes
rm -rf ~/.adobe
rm -rf ~/.macromedia

Then open Chromium / Firefox fresh and give it a try!
```

This is what I did and have DRM FLash videos working smoothly in Chrome on Ubuntu using the Adobe Flash plugin with HAL installed.