# Miro does not play Flash and HTML5 videos

Tags: video, flash, podcast, html5, miro

I wanted to watch the Olympics, so I installed Miro 5.0.2 (49960df1) on Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit. After downloading the Olympics podcasts, I tried to watch the live streams but I was greeted with these messages despite the fact that I already had Adobe Flash 11.2 installed on my system:

[image]

[image]

So I tried installing the one from Adobe's website, too. The same video runs without any problem in the browser, but not in Miro. I get the same message every time.

I'd really appreciate any help in solving this problem so that I could watch the live streams on Miro itself.

Comment: Does it play other youtube videos?

Comment: Yes. It plays youtube videos without any problem.

Comment: Cf. [How do I fix Flash issues](http://askubuntu.com/q/86164/19753)...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you try this from user79939 at [How can I watch the NBC Olympics 2012 (USA)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169318/how-can-i-watch-the-nbc-olympics-2012-usa). If it works the basic problem is that the streams are protected content.

---

As per [this post](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/flash-player-11-problems-playing.html) on the Adobe website:

Step One: Install HAL

sudo apt-get install hal

Step Two: Quit your web browser

Step Three: Clean out the Adobe Flash folder:

cd ~/.adobe/Flash_Player
rm -rf NativeCache AssetCache APSPrivateData2

This process worked for me.  In my case, I'd been able to go to nbcolympics.com and click the log to begin the verification process, but never given the chance to enter my Comcast credentials.  Doing the steps above fixed everything.

Comment: Apparently, that didn't solve the problem. Hal was already installed and I cleaned the Adobe Flash folder too. I'm using Chromium as the default browser. I tried using Firefox as the default browser, but that too didn't help.