# Is there a work around to get protected Hulu or Amazon Prime instant videos working?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, flash

When I went to watch some only episodes of star trek on Amazon Prime, the player would get stuck on updating. I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/149205/114660) and doing so actually worked for 3 seconds. It was the oddest thing. Clearly the video was playing and I saw 3 seconds of the episode, but a message came up saying I needed to update my flash player. I tried loading videos over and over again, but no success, not even the 3 seconds. Here is the error message:

```
Sorry we were unable to stream this video. This is likely because your Flash Player needs to be updated.
```

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail, Firefox 20, and adobe flash-player 11,2,202,280. Apparently Adobe isn't going to make newer versions of flash available for Linux, only security updates.

So has anyone been able to play prime instant videos, and if so, under what circumstances? Is there perhaps an alternative implementation of the flash plugin I can use? Or is the cause of my problem something different altogether?

---

Problem probably has to do with the version of flash being used. If anyone has gotten Prime to work with an my current version of flash or an open-source/free implementation of it, please do tell. Or if anyone can get videos on amazon to play with any other parameters aside from changing my browser to chrome, please tell me.

This also affects [protected content in Hulu](http://www.hulu.com/support/article/23184736) and other services that employ DRM through Flash.

---

What hasn't worked:

- Using Chrome which has the newest version of flash via ppapi. Amazon Prime strictly prohibits it.
- Using Chromium has the same issue as using firefox
- Trying to install Adobe Flash 11,2,202,275. Is not compatible with raring libraries(?).

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer since I'm not satisfied with it. So Adobe decided to make new versions of flash for linux using Pepper plug-in API developed by google instead of the Netscape plug-in API used by every other browser except Internet Explorer which uses Active X. Reasons _why_ they did this would instill much debate. However, Amazon Prime requires I guess the newest version of flash which maybe is the problem. Anyone know any forks of firefox that has the ppapi? The only work around I can see is using chrome, which doesn't answer the question.

Comment: gah, even though I specified that this question is for firefox, I should point out that I can't install the pepper-based flash plugin for chromium either.

Comment: I doubt it will help, but you can try Gnash, which is an open-source implementation of Flash. IIRC, however, it's outdated (I'm not sure though).

Comment: @strugee it's worth a try. The main issue the Amazon has is that it wants a player that supports digital rights management. Edit: Oh drats, turns out that it supports up to swf 7 and some of swf 8 and 9. No flash 11...

Comment: I tried installed proper Google Chrome (not Chromium) as well.  Had to symlink the old udev library to get it to run, but it still didn't work.

Comment: @SajanParikh you're right, I tried to install Chrome after all other roads failed. The .deb file opened with ubuntu software center, and said that the libudev0 dependency was not satisfied. I searched on Synaptic package manager and it wasn't there. found this http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/FyszF27mzIc where the user says it's been removed from the repositories (dafuq, why is this so hard?!?) and another user gives an alternative link to download it. I'll update u on if it works...

Comment: @nil, you don't need to actually install libudev.so.0 as in 13.04 libudev.so.1 exists.  If you simply force the install, ignoring the dependency check, then symlink libudev.so.0 to the existing libudev.so.1, you can get Chrome to run just fine.

Comment: @SajanParikh oh... lol, hmm, well regardless, amazon specifically rejects ppapi and says to use firefox, which has me asking dafuq? Is it really the case that Amazon refuses to support linux? Only thing I can think of is running firefox through wine. Well, might as well, then I can use the Unity browser plug-in (not related at all to the unity desktop environment, just the same name) to play some browser based games.

Comment: EUREKA, this might be the smoking gun. This thread [here](http://www.amazon.com/forum/amazon%20video%20on%20demand?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx3EQAX98ED5WQ3&cdThread=Tx1D5LHTP2HWMRQ) suggest using an _older_ version of flash. Kind of heading in the opposite direction of all other solutions, but people report using 11,2,202,275 as working.

Comment: yeah...having issues finding 11.2.202.275....maybe i'll pick this up tomorrow and update to whether or not this was a solution

Comment: tried downloading it from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/i386/flashplugin-installer/11.2.202.275ubuntu0.12.10.1). Uninstalled flash via synaptic package manage. Opened the deb file with software center. Seemed to install fine. Restarted firefox, but flash player wouldn't load. It was a grey box on multiple websites, amazon said i didn't even have the flash player. Upgraded it back to 11.2.202.280 using synaptic package manager. *cries* I'm sure there is a solution somewhere....

Comment: I don't think it's a flash issue now.  I just looked on my 12.10 installation where it is all working just fine, it and it has the same version of Flash as on my 13.04 where it doesn't work. 11.2.202.280

Comment: o dang, wonder what could be causing the problem then? Well, wine works at the very least. Maybe someone should file a bug report and leave this question as a work around?

Comment: @SajanParikh I don't know the details of how, but you could probably use the equivs package to fix the Chrome dependency issue.

Comment: @strugee I got Chrome running just fine.  I was just telling Nil.  You have to force the installation without the dependency check as the packages Chrome depends on don't exist in 13.04.  Then you have to symlink the new 13.04 udev library to where Chrome expects it to be and everything works flawlessly.

Comment: @SajanParikh right, I'm just saying that if you don't like having a weird install with regards to deps, equivs is an option.

Comment: @SajanParikh Telling you this a little late, but there was a [question](http://askubuntu.com/q/286075/114660) asked about Chromes dependency issues some time ago. I liked your comment here on how to go about it. Could you add it as an answer to that question?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I did the following on 13.04 64bit:

```
sudo apt-get install hal

sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi/preprobe

sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi/information

/usr/sbin/hald --daemon=yes --verbose=yes

rm -rf ~/.adobe
```

That got things up and going in Chromium....

Commenters also confirmed that the same instructions work for 12.04 64bit.

Comment: This works beautifully. Better than firefox in wine! Would you mind explaining what the problem was and why this fix works? Also, I'm running the 32 bit version of raring, so it works for both versions.

Comment: This fix also made it work in firefox. You are the man!

Comment: Amazing!  Would be great for someone to explain this a bit more though.  Glad things are working again.  From the fix, it looks like it was an issue with HAL.

Comment: Apparently hal isn't working properly on 13.04. It is missing directories and not running when it is supposed to. Seems that hal functionality is being roled into udev.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. I understand that udev replaced hal, but since hal is still provided and still required for Flash DRM, perhaps a bug should be filed?

Comment: hald isn't available out of the box in 13.04, so you might want to tip future readers to install it with `apt-get install hal`

Comment: Could you explain exactly what these commands do? I'd be interested to know the specifics of why this fixes the problem.

Comment: I tried this fix with Chromium and received this error message (Firefox works): If you're using the Chrome browser with Linux, you must disable PPAPI to continue using Amazon Instant Video. You can also use a different Web browser, like Firefox.

Comment: This fixed all broken content for me except for TheComedyNetwork.ca, which is how I stream the Daily Show in Canada... any advice?

Comment: This is no longer required in 13.04 at least in Firefox as of version 23.

Comment: I can confirm that this works in 12.04 as well.

Comment: None of these mentioned here worked for me. I am using Xubuntu 13.10. I have installed the package adobe-flashplugin and it worked immediately. I don't have reputation, so, I hope it helps someone like me.

Comment: This still works in Ubuntu 14.04. Nice solution, thx.

Answer (score 7):

The other solutions here haven't worked for me in **13.10 64bit**. The only thing that does is adding a ppa :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mjblenner/ppa-hal
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install hal
```

That worked in Chrome.

Thanks Michael Blennerhassett for the ppa

Thanks omgubuntu for providing the instructions I got the answer from:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/10/fixing-amazon-prime-streaming-drm-protected-flash-13-10

Comment: I can confirm that this also works in 14.04 64bit. In my case, I installed flash for Firefox, then installed HAL, and all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Code the Following:

```
sudo apt-get install hal

hald
```

(This works for version 12.10 I apologized. I forgot I have not upgrade my laptop yet)

**For version 13.04 ( I am running Xunbuntu on my Desktop**)

In my case I did have to download hal and run hald

then I made the same changes from the answer above

```
sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi/preprobe

sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi/information

/usr/sbin/hald --daemon=yes --verbose=yes

rm -rf ~/.adobe
```

**I got an error the first time I copy and paste this line**

```
/usr/sbin/hald --daemon=yes --verbose=yes
```

But once I installed hal and run hald it worked.

I can watch amazon prime video using Firefox.

Comment: not for 13.04 raring ringtail..

Comment: Thanks I forgot I am running 12.10 in my laptop. Reposted what I did to make it work on 13.04

Comment: This worked for me. Renaming/deleting the old Adobe folder did the trick (after installing and making the modifications to HAL).

Answer (score 1):

<del>As of today, April 27, 2013, I have found no other solution to watching Amazon Prime instant videos on Ubuntu aside from the following:</del>

1. Install Wine from the Ubuntu repository.
2. Install the latest [version of Firefox for Windows](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/) using Wine. The version of Wine I used was 1.4.1. I have noticed no bugs when doing so.
3. Download the [Windows installer for latest version of Adobe Flash Player](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/) and run it using Wine. I noticed no bugs when doing so.

When playing videos on Amazon Prime, I notice no artifacts or anything that would detract from the viewing experience. Even with the extra layer of compatibility, it runs just as if it were native. If another solution appears in the future that doesn't require Wine, I will update that as the correct answer.

Comment: you're using the version of Wine straight from the Ubuntu repos, right?

Comment: @strugee yeah..