# Trying to watch Hulu, need hal

Tags: apt, video, flash

I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I cant let you watch hulu. -- hal
I I tried to watch a video on hulu.com. Just as I thought it might play, I got a message saying I need to install hal, and do some other non-sense.
So I went to [the website shown](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/flash-player-11-problems-playing.html) and tried what it suggested. `sudo apt-get install hal`
 which then stated, that is not a package. so I looked for libhal, and hal, and did not find it.

I installed Adobe Flash from source, so I have the panel, where I was able to complete the other required steps.. but Im stuck on the package requirement for hal.

What do other Ubuntu Users do to play hulu? Is there an HTML5 player I should know about? Is the package hal worth tacking down and installing?

Comment: did you try google chrome?  I hate using google stuff but just for watching videos i think it doesn't give trouble.  You could even put it in a jail like i do.

Comment: how do i jail Google Chrome? yes, I too dislike google stuff.

Comment: you could use many things like chroot or even docker if you wanted.

Comment: There's a PPA listed in http://askubuntu.com/a/410603/158442 which you might be able to use

Comment: solved it! created a new problem.. but thats a new question I recon