# can't stream video from HBO GO on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: flash, video-streaming

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 on an ideapad P500.  I have watched videos from HBO, but suddenly my computer stopped streaming them.  I do get the introductory HBO screen, but then it shows the message "Optimizing Video Quality" forever.

First I thought it was the TV company, but I was able to stream it on another computer; together with a few blogposts that I found, I come to think the problem lies in my computer.

I tried checking the flash plugins, but couldn't find anything. And then I even did a clean reinstall of Ubuntu 13.04, and still with no luck.

I have searched around, but I am not an expert on such matters.  Any help will be apppreciated.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: I have the same problem...

Comment: See answer to this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/145735/adobe-flash-player-not-working-with-amazon-prime has to do with flash...

Comment: See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/311021/88802) to the question @bytebender linked. I think it will apply here too.